# How to use {loc_physical_ms} to get city and ZIP code on your website?

Tags: api, google-ads-api

So I have a client that wants to do a Google Ad campaign for certain locations. From what we gathered, you can set up location of interest and pass on a parameter {loc_physical_ms} that can be used to get some details based on that ID. My question is, how do I access that info? Is it by using an API? I did looked at the reference here:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting

But it is not explained how I can use that ID on my website to get something like the ZIP code and city of the click. I been looking around, but to no avail. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the solution. So for anyone that may come across this, that link I have above provides you with a CSV with the latest Geo Target list. I was under the impression that Google would provide an API for us to use, but that is not the case here. You will have to import that data into your database, and then use it from there. So once you have that data in your database, you can then just make a query that will use the ID from the parameter {loc_physical_ms} from the database as reference for your query.

Comment: Were you ever able to confirm the `{loc_physical_ms}` parameter actually works? I have it in my tracking template but have never seen it populated.

Comment: Update: according to my google analytics I see it is getting set! I just wasn't able to find a way to test it besides running it live and waiting for the analytics.